# Mac App Store: Is Sandboxing the App mandatory?

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox, accessibility-api

I need to distribute my app without sandboxing, because I need the accessibility API. Does anyone know if the app will be rejected if I submit without sandboxing turned on (with a good reason)?

In the Mac [App Store Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/mac/resources/approval/guidelines.html) it's written:

> Apps that are not sandboxed appropriately may be rejected

What is your experience with that statement? "May be" or "Will be"?

Comment: I don't do much Mac development but if it is anything like iOS then they will reject it, but based on that ruling in the guidelines I would say it would definitely get rejected if it wasn't sandboxed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, since June, 2012 sandboxing is mandatory - all apps submitted to Mac App Store must be sandboxed.
If your app doesn't support work in sandboxed environment you should distribute it from your site, signed with Developer ID certificate (or not signed at all).